# Как реализовать replace в C++ с string

Tags: c++

Есть предположим переменные abc1, abc2, в abc1 есть "Hello" а в abc2 есть "Kivy!", можно ли как то убрать "Kivy!" и написать туда World! с помощью replace? почитал гугл, ничего не понял!

```
#include "mouseBTC.h"
#include "computte.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{ 
 string abc1 = "Hello";
 string abc2 = "Kivy!";

 // Тут нужен replace, но как его сделать? 
 work.replace(work.begin(), work.end(), "212", "123"); // не работает. Нормально только с char :(


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Возможно, Вам поможет эта ссылка:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/replace/

А вообще - проблема возникает из за того, что в других языках стандартная функция replace может быть вызвана с аргументами "строка, которую надо заменить" и "строка, на которую надо заменить". А при использовании c++ придется то же самое делать в два шага: сначала найти в строке подстроку, которую надо заменить, а уже потом применить replace.

Comment: Вот здесь этот вопрос разбирается, там есть функция, которая реализует поиск и замену и решение через регэкспы: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418231/replace-part-of-a-string-with-another-string